# java - set windows default fontsize programmatically

Tags: windows, javafx, default, font-size

I have a JavaFX application, and on different computers (screen resolution) some pane or text field slip away from each other. I found it is due to the Windows default font size (small - 100%, medium - 125%, etc.) depends on the screen resolution.

Is there any way to set this default font size for my application programmatically?

Comment: That's the DPI setting.  You cannot change it.

Comment: It's okay that it depends on the DPI. But if I change the default font size in the Windows Control Panel for example from "Medium - 125%" to "Small - 100%", it solves the problem. It is impossible to change it from my program?

Comment: **Do not mess with the user's settings**.  There are few better ways to make users hate you then to make their text unreadable because your layout doesn't work with high-DPI.  You should fix your layout.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx